# Usual Limit and Eventual Probability are equal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Suppose, $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of independently distributed sequence of discrete random variables with parameters $\lambda_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. All $X_i$'s follow the same distribution, but with different parameters.

Now, suppose all $X_i$'s take some value $a\in\mathbb{R}$ . Then, I'm trying to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n=a) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = a~~\text{eventually} )$$ Is this statement always true ? If yes, can we justify this rigorously ?

Comment: What do you mean by "$X_n = a$ eventually"?  If it means "there exists $N$ such that $X_n=a$ for all $n>N$", then the answer to your question is definitely no in general because (by independence) the RHS will be 0